# why doesn't SMIL animation work when I add it dynamically using HTML dom

Tags: javascript, svg, xhtml, smil

I have a files with creates svg hexagons (polygon) dynamically, I have made each hexagon as a object instance in order to reference them latter.

this is my hexagon class

```
function Hexagon(cx,cy,side,id){
    //console.log('hexagon');

    this.cx=cx;
    this.cy=cy;
    this.side=side;
    this.id=id;

    this.isBtn=false;


};

Hexagon.prototype.makeHex =makeHex; //You set the prototype, but don't actually execute the function
Hexagon.prototype.setBtn=setBtn;
Hexagon.prototype.shine=shine;
```

Most prototype functions in the object work as expected but the shine function.

The shine method adds(atleast tries to add) SMIL animation to the referencing hexagon, Here is the method

```
function shine(){
    var hex=document.getElementById(this.id)

    var smil=document.createElement('animate');
    smil.setAttribute('attributeName','fill');
    smil.setAttribute('to','#332299');
    smil.setAttribute('dur','2s');
    smil.setAttribute('begin',this.id+'.mouseover')

    hex.appendChild(smil);

}
```

Now the html node is appended but the smil animation doesn't seem to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/Snedden27/d6qbLzjv/

If you inspect the hexagon right below the second orange hexagon .It does contain the smil animate tag but the animation doesn't seem to work.

PS:Also to demonstrate that smil works if not applied dynamically , I have create a rect with smil animation,you can see it if you remove the onload event which fills the screen with hexagons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create any SVG elements (including animate) via createElement, you need to use createElementNS and pass the SVG namespace as the first argument e.g.

```
var smil=document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate');
```

Here's a [fixed version](https://jsfiddle.net/d6qbLzjv/1/) of your test